# Coloring partial text within cells in Excel

Tags: regex, excel, vba, batch-processing

I need to have everything that is in [square brackets] and all HTML/XML tags in these `<brackets>` colored in generic red on a selected sheet across all cells. The rest of the text in the cells needs to stay black.

I have tried modifying the attached code but was only able to get the brackets turned to red whereas the rest of the text was left in black. I guess I need to add the regex ranges `\[.*?\]` and `\<.*?\>` but not sure how. Please help!

```
Sub Format_Characters_In_Found_Cell()
Dim Found As Range, x As String, FoundFirst As Range

x = "["
y = "]"

On Error Resume Next
Set Found = Cells.Find(what:=x, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    Set FoundFirst = Found
    Do
      'Format "x"
        With Found.Characters(Start:=InStr(Found.Text, x), Length:=Len(y))
            .Font.ColorIndex = 3
            .Font.Bold = False
        End With
        Set Found = Cells.FindNext(Found)
    Loop Until FoundFirst.Address = Found.Address
Else
    MsgBox x & " could not be found.", , " "
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: `Len(y)` should possibly be `Instr(Found.Txt, y) - Instr(Found.Txt, x) + 1` (or, if you don't want the `[` and `]` themselves to be coloured red, use `Start:=InStr(Found.Text, x) + 1, Length:=Instr(Found.Txt, y) - Instr(Found.Txt, x) - 1`)

Comment: @YowE3K it does not work that way at all if I set With to:

`With Found.Characters(Start:=InStr(Found.Text, x), Length:=InStr(Found.Txt, y) - InStr(Found.Txt, x) + 1)` 

per your instructions. Any ideas?

Comment: on this row:
`With Found.Characters(Start:=InStr(Found.Text, x), Length:=Len(y))`
the `Length:=` value is 1. you need it to be the distance between the number of chars being turned red.

Comment: Yeah - I have an idea - enroll me in typing lessons.  (`Txt` should have been `Text`.  I found it while testing it before creating an answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Len(y)` (when `y` contains a single character) will always return a value of 1.

The correct length you are after is the number of characters between where `x` exists in the string and where `y` exists in the string, so you need to use something like:

```
With Found.Characters(Start:=InStr(Found.Text, x), _
                      Length:=Instr(Found.Text, y) - Instr(Found.Text, x) + 1)
```

or, if you wanted to not colour the brackets themselves, you could add 1 to the start position and subtract 2 from the length, thus giving:

```
With Found.Characters(Start:=InStr(Found.Text, x) + 1, _
                      Length:=Instr(Found.Text, y) - Instr(Found.Text, x) - 1)
```

---

To cater for both `[...]` and `<...>` my preference would be to modify the subroutine to allow the type of bracket being searched for to be passed as a parameter, and then call the subroutine twice.

```
Sub Test
    Format_Characters_In_Found_Cell "[", "]"
    Format_Characters_In_Found_Cell "<", ">"
End Sub

Sub Format_Characters_In_Found_Cell(x As String, y As String)
Dim Found As Range, FoundFirst As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set Found = Cells.Find(what:=x, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    Set FoundFirst = Found
    Do
      'Format "x"
        With Found.Characters(Start:=InStr(Found.Text, x), _
                              Length:=Instr(Found.Text, y) - Instr(Found.Text, x) + 1)
            .Font.ColorIndex = 3
            .Font.Bold = False
        End With
        Set Found = Cells.FindNext(Found)
    Loop Until FoundFirst.Address = Found.Address
Else
    MsgBox x & " could not be found.", , " "
End If 
End Sub
```

---

Iterative, and allowing for multiple instances of brackets within a single cell:

```
Sub Format_Characters_In_Found_Cell(x As String, y As String)
Dim Found As Range, FoundFirst As Range
Dim posStart As Long
Dim posEnd As Long

On Error Resume Next
Set Found = Cells.Find(what:=x, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    Set FoundFirst = Found
    Do
      'Format "x"
        posStart = InStr(Found.Text, x)
        Do While posStart > 0
            posEnd = InStr(posStart + 1, Found.Text, y)
            If posEnd = 0 Then
                Exit Do ' no matching end bracket
            End If
            With Found.Characters(Start:=posStart, Length:=posEnd - posStart + 1)
                .Font.ColorIndex = 3
                .Font.Bold = False
            End With
            posStart = InStr(posEnd + 1, Found.Text, x)
        Loop
        Set Found = Cells.FindNext(Found)
    Loop Until FoundFirst.Address = Found.Address
Else
    MsgBox x & " could not be found.", , " "
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you! 

Would it be possible to include `<>` as well for HTML/XML tags and `{}` for variables, e.g. regex 'or' into the `x = "[|<|{"
y = "]|>|}"` strings? Not sure how to add them here not to create several modules...

Comment: @Ilia - your last comment got cut off because of (I assume) the `<`, but I have taken a guess at what you were going to ask and have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Ilia - Using regexs would allow you to process all the bracket types at once, but it would then be difficult to `Find` them all at once.  You would probably have to process all Cells, rather than just the ones that the `Find` locates, and I think it will be more efficient to use `Find` several times rather than going down that route.

Comment: Agreed. Added 4 sumbodules to your solution to account for all brackets variations and variable expressions. Thank you!

Comment: @ilia - is it the `</ ...>` that isn't being processed correctly, or simply all cases where there are multiple occurrences of a bracket within a cell, e.g. `"gdashgd [hadkjdh] adakhsdlk [asdkajh] asgdjahg"`.  The current code will only highlight the first one it finds.

Comment: @Ilia Updated answer to loop through all bracket pairs in each cell.

Comment: Yup, the first solution was only taking care of the first iteration of the pairs of brackets. Thank you for coming up with the iterative version as well. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Format_Characters_In_Found_Cell()
Dim Found As Range, x As String, FoundFirst As Range

x = "["
y = "]"

On Error Resume Next
Set Found = Cells.Find(what:=x, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    Set FoundFirst = Found
    Do
      'Format "x"
        l = InStr(Found.Text, y) - InStr(Found.Text, x) + 1
        With Found.Characters(Start:=InStr(Found.Text, x), Length:=l)
            .Font.ColorIndex = 3
            .Font.Bold = False
        End With
        Set Found = Cells.FindNext(Found)
    Loop Until FoundFirst.Address = Found.Address
Else
    MsgBox x & " could not be found.", , " "
End If
End Sub
```